# Sharepoint 2013 Custom Web Service getting 401

Tags: wcf, sharepoint-2013

Created a custom web service that is deployed as a farm solution to SP2013. Added managed path to ISAPI folder for this service in the VS Project.

Added C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\80

```
  <location path="_vti_bin/FCWebServices.svc">
      <system.web>
        <authorization>
          <allow users="*" />
        </authorization>
      </system.web>
  </location>
```

Also added C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\web.config

```
<location path="FCWebServices.svc">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Calling from IE or Chrome the appropriate path "http://host/_vti_bin/FCWebServices.svc/GetOffCanvasNavigation" -- I get a the expected data back as a HTTP 200. Calling from JQuery $.ajax call I get a 401 (just calling the webservice method itself, even with any SP2013 API calls commented out).

I would like for this web service call to be anonymous and it will be on a public facing SharePoint 2013 site.

Here is the headers dump of the web request:

```
   Request URL: http://host/_vti_bin/FCWebServices.svc/GetOffCanvasNavigation
   Request Method: OPTIONS
   Status Code: 401 / Unauthorized
 - Request Headers
   Accept: */*
   Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
   Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type, accept
   Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
   Cache-Control: no-cache
   Connection: Keep-Alive
   Content-Length: 0
   Host: fcit-mcvm2
   Origin: file:
   User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2486.0 Safari/537.36 Edge/13.10586
 - Response Headers
   Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
   Content-Length: 16
   Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
   Date: Mon, 06 Jun 2016 14:50:50 GMT
   Location: /_login/default.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2f_vti_bin%2fFCWebServices.svc%2fGetOffCanvasNavigation
   MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 15.0.0.4569
   request-id: eb85839d-472b-d06e-9fc9-c1e40fcec15a
   Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
   SPIisLatency: 155
   SPRequestDuration: 1336
   SPRequestGuid: eb85839d-472b-d06e-9fc9-c1e40fcec15a
   WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
   X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
   X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN
   X-MS-InvokeApp: 1; RequireReadOnly
   X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
```

Console error logged:

```
HTTP401: DENIED - The requested resource requires user authentication.
(XHR): OPTIONS - http://host/_vti_bin/FCWebServices.svc/GetOffCanvasNavigation
```

Any ideas what I need to do to eliminate the 401's?

Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a Web API2 solution outside of sharepoint and integrated with CSOM. In order to accomplish what I wanted to do originally, I would have had to do a lot of header hacking and work around's in SharePoint and hope it did not break.